# Executable jar running slower than Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, executable

My program works perfectly fine when I run from eclipse but I package it to an executable jar and run it from command line, it runs much slower (almost five times slower). I am even setting the -vmargs while executing the jar 
           java -Xms40m -Xmx512m -jar jarFile.jar
I do not have any older version of java on my machine. I am not able to understand what I am missing over here. How can eclipse run the same program faster while using the same version of  java and same vm arguments. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
karthik

Comment: the jar is a little bit slower because it has to be uncompressed while executing, but 5times slower is very long. what size has the jar file? maybe there are not needed ressources in the jar file.

Answer (score 9):

We had a similar issue but the problem was that while exporting Java code as a runnable jar file from eclipse, we were choosing an option "Package Required Libraries into generated jar". This was putting all of the referenced libraries as jar files within the runnable jar, which probably was being unpackaged during every run. Instead of that we used "Extract required libraries into generated jar" option while creating the runnable jar file and the speed of the execution of jar shot up - almost same as it was while running the code within eclipse.

Comment: We spent few hours yesterday in figuring it out, but just noticed that some people had posted this in SO already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22685103/runnable-jar-runs-too-slow-compared-to-eclipse-project

Comment: I can confirm that this made a *huge* difference with my runnable JAR file. In Windows it ran at least *20* times faster, one minute versus approx. 20-25 minutes.

Comment: just made this change, JAR file went to the moon, super fast, awesome tip!

Comment: "Copy required libraries into sub-folder" works fine too

Answer (score 1):

You most likely print a lot to System.out/System.err (either directly or through logging).  The Windows terminal emulator needs to render your output, and does it slower than Eclipse.

Try redirecting all output to a file or NUL and measure again.

Comment: I am not using any System.out statements but my log file is huge, do you think that's one of the reasons?

Comment: Perhaps.  Profile with jvisualvm in the Oracle JDK and see where the time goes.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking "Package Required Libraries into generated jar",
use "Extract required libraries into generated jar" option while creating the runnable jar file. This saves a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. The `eclipse` took 5 seconds to run the application while the `jar` took 3 minutes. This is due to the way I exported the runnable `jar` file.

These are mainly two ways to export as a Runnable `jar` in `eclipse`.

**1). Package required libraries into jar**

- This will add actual `jar` files of the libraries into your `jar`.
  This is the cleanest since it separates application class files with
  library JARs.
- The downside is this makes runnable jar perform very slow.

**2). Extract required libraries into generated jar**

- This way will extract only the actual class files from the libraries
  that your application uses and includes in the runnable `jar` file.
  As a result your Jar file will include your application class files
  as well as class files of all the libraries used by your application.
- ***This method makes runnable jar perform just like it is run in your
  `eclipse` IDE.***
- Using this way I was able to run jar application without any lag and
  completed just as I run in `eclipse` IDE taking 5 seconds.